# "Weak" and "strong" spectral lines

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

Can some one please explain what the following excerpt from Priest's MHD of the sun means:

> The lowest is an extremely thin layer of plasma only several hundred kilometers thick, called the photosphere (Sec. 1.4), which is relatively dense and opaque and emits most of the solar radiation. It has an optical thickness τ $\lesssim$  1 in the near-ultraviolet, visible and near-infrared continua, but is optically thick in all except the weakest spectral lines.

In particular what are weak (and strong) spectral lines?

Also, when astronomers present an image of the sun in say H$\alpha$ (15000K), does it mean only regions/phenomena with H$\alpha$ transitions are visible(eg. the chromosphere)? Does the continuum black body radiation
also contribute? The blackbody spectrum is peaked at a different wavelength (6000K), so my guess is it contributes very few H$\alpha$ wavelength photons in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak and strong would refer to a product of the density $n$ of  the species doing the absorbing (including what quantum state it is in) and the cross-section  $\sigma$ (or equivalently, oscillator strength) of the transition.

A strong line would have a large $n\sigma$. This could lead to a large optical depth for any photon at the wavelength corresponding to the transition that traverses the atmospheric layer in question. i.e. The layer is effectively opaque at that wavelength. Conversely, a weak line would have a small $n\sigma$ and the optical depth might be much less than 1, meaning that the atmospheric layer is effectively transparent at that wavelength.

A H-alpha image is just an image through a filter that allows photons with wavelengths close to 656.3 nm to pass. That includes photons from all sources. The photospheric continuum at 656.3 mm would be faint compared with the strong H-alpha line emission from active regions, which is why the filter allows you to pick those regions out.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. Few clarifications though: $n$ here would be the number density of hydrogen atoms (neutral but excited) with the electron in $n=3$ state? 


And $\sigma$ is related to the Einstein coefficients, right? Is the H$\alpha$ emission thermal, like can we definitely conclude that the parts emitting those are at the corresponding temperatures (this is the reason I was converting wavelengths to temperature in my question)?

Comment: @duality $n$ and $\sigma$ are defined. The latter would be proportional to the Einstein coefficients or the oscillator strength. The chromospheric plasma responsible for H alpha emission is hotter than the photosphere. There is no single temperature that can be assigned. 15,000 K would be capable of ionising all hydrogen so is probably a bit too hot.

Comment: Ok the first part was answered already, sorry for repetition.  The second one, when you say "hot", is the temperature the temperature of equilibrium thermodynamics or more of a phenomenological/observational measure of "hotness"? What I read from the comment is that it is the later, as you say no single temperature can be assigned. Thank you.

Comment: @duality the temperature you would assign assuming that any point in the plasma is in local thermodynamic equilibrium. No single temperature can be assigned to "the chromosphere" for example. The fact that H alpha emission will peak (because of the competing requirements of having an un-ionised population in the $n=3$ level) at around 10,000 K, means you see structures at around that temperature.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.